# Получение RAW изображения с камеры мобильного устройства в React-native?

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, react-native

Я не обладаю обширным опытом в мобильной разработке и тем более в React-native.

Задача следующая, получать фотографии с мобильного устройства в формате RAW (с минимальной программой работкой). "Сырые" изображения требуеются для обучения нейросети, на данный момент многие камеры мобильников отдают уже обработанное изображение, на которое применяется шумоподавление и т.д., что очень негативно сказывается на конечном изображении. На современных устройствах iPhone 11 шумоподавление может быть очень агрессивным и затирает некоторые объекты на фото.

1) Можно ли получить RAW в JS треде ?

2) Можно ли получить RAW в нативном треде через реализацию нативного модуля ?

Нужно понимать можно ли это сделать как для Anroid так и для IOS.
Готовое решение разумеется не нужно, просто нужно понимать, можно ли это реализовать вообще.

Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Comment: Да, RAW нативно получить можно. См. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/capturing_still_and_live_photos/capturing_photos_in_raw_format

Comment: Получить Raw нативно можно, разумеется вопрос - можно ли получить RAW через реализацию нативного модуля или потребуется реализовать библиотеку по аналогии с react-native-camera ?